# Append text to textfield while typing

Tags: swift

I have a textfield in which a user will enter their weight. The textfield starts with no text. Once the user begins typing, I want the textfield to display "the current number entered" + " LBs".

For example when typing in my weight of 180 LBs:

before editing:

```
textfield.text = nil
```

user enters 1:

```
textfield.text = "1 LBs"
```

user enters 8:

```
textfield.text = "18 LBs"
```

user enters 0:

```
textfield.text = "180 LBs"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to import UITextFieldDelegate.

```
class myClass: UITextFieldDelegate
```

Then in viewDidload delegate your UITextFeild

```
textField.delegate = self //PUT the name of your textField
```

Then add this code also

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Then call this function

```
func textFieldChanged(textField: UITextField) {

   if textfield.text != "" {
     textfield.text = "\(self.enteredNumber) + LBS"
   }
}
```